# How to transfer data via UART that is read form another module using SPO at a faster rate?

Tags: spi, uart, communication

I'm using a [VS1053](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/vs1053.pdf),to do a PCM recording for 1 minute by using STM32l4 microcontroller.

The data is read from the VS1053 at 16 MHz, the sampling rate is 8000 sps and each sample is 2 bytes, which makes it 128 kbs to be sent.

I was using a UART to send this data to another module at 230,400 baud but I had to reduce this to 115,200 baud as the Bluetooth module the UART connects to does not support 230,400 baud.

Now the data is acquired at a faster rate than sending. The VS1053 has a buffer form which I read 512 bytes each time via SPI. How can I handle this situation to send all the bytes via UART without losing it?

Comment: Speed the UART up. If data is coming in, faster than it's going out, you can buffer (if it's for a short period of time, and you have enough memory), speed it up going out, lose it, or compress it somehow.

Comment: I cannot increase the UART baud rate as the module to which I communicate do not support high rates, I have no enough RAM to buffer it as well

Comment: why is it down voted? , is that a wrong question?

Comment: I can think of one reason: You're somewhat obviously asking for an impossible thing here, and you probably know it as well. You can't send the data and you can't buffer it. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: My be I can reduce the samples , like sending every alternate samples? or send only the 8 bit values skipping the higher bits? or any algorithms that might help? I think I overestimated StackOverflow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks to do something that is not possible and has been abandoned by the asker for a year and a half

Answer (score 0):

> How can I handle this situation to send all the bytes via UART without
>   losing it?

If the final recipient of the data cannot handle the natural data rate that is being transmitted then you only realistically have two options: -

1. Throw away data
2. Buffer the 1 minute's worth of data and ship it out at a slower rate compatible with the final recipient.

You don't need much RAM to do (2), about 8 Mbits maximum.

Comment: Actually you only need about 800 kbits since you can still push out 115 kbit/s so the buffer isn't filling up quite as fast.

Comment: @pipe yes, so I changed my final sentence to state maximum!

Comment: Ah the phantom downvoter strikes twice today. If anyone can see an obvious mistake in what I've written I'd appreciate heads up.

Comment: Wasn't me! Some people downvote answers to questions which are obviously off-topic, but in this case it's weird.

Comment: @pipe yeah I knew it wasn't you!

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, The encoding is done at 8000 sps , can I skip alternate samples and make it 4000 sps ? In that case I can still send the data via UART.

Comment: I can't see any reason this had a downvote.

Comment: @ArunJoe only you can say whether skipping samples is OK. It comes down to aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

IF you need to send *continuous* data at that rate within those constraints, the only possible way is to compress it somehow. Either lossless or lossy compression is possible.

But it clearly depends on the information content or “whiteness” of the data, I.e., bandwidth and dynamic range. It also depends on the processing power you have available.

If your bandwidth is low enough, you can simply filter and subsample. If the dynamic range is low enough you can throw bits away.

If the slew-rate of the data is low enough, a method that is somewhat generic and with wide applicability is delta-coding of the data, that is calculate the difference between successive samples and only send that.

In voice, where large changes mask small ones, data compansion is commonly used.

If there are data patterns that are much more frequent than others lossless Huffman encoding would work. If you have the processing power, you can even implement a full Lempel-Ziv algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

Use two parallel serial channels.

Comment: This is really poor advice: it sounds simple but in practice the OP will struggle with data synchronization and may be simply not feasible with OP's hardware